# Implementation of Spring security in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am new to Spring security. I want to implement it in my AngularJS app. After authentication it must redirect to a page based on roles, like if is it admin it must redirect to `admin.html` and if it is user it must redirect to `user.html`.

Comment: What have you managed to do so far?

Comment: I followed this https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii , i want to know how username and password is passed to the authenticationmanager and it is authenticated ? from angularjs and redirect to different page based on roles like i mentioned above .thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through Spring security [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) can be of great help.

If you want to be more familiar with some working project model. This [site](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/) offers some great working project.
This [project](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-hibernate-role-based-login-example/) will give you an easier understanding of ROLE based authentication.

I have also done a simple project for my office internship. if it is any help to you, heres the [link](https://github.com/50417/PinPeaks).

Comment: thanks a lot sohil , can it be done using authenticationsuccess handler and authentication failure handler . and if i am passing the credentials from angular , which method in spring security to be invoked . can you pls help me in this regard .. thanking you in advance

Comment: You can definitely do it with Custom Authetication Success Handler as well . AngularJS is basically a view. 
Spring Security Authentication can be overriden by implementing UserDetailsService Class which is the core Spring Security interface which loads user-specific data.
Here's a project [link](https://github.com/50417/annotationcrud). You can  look into the services package for better understanding.

Comment: thanks a lot sohil , in normal authentication we call the method j_spring_security_check to send the data . likewise what will be the method for rest api . which will be a better approach basic auth , or anyother standards . pls enlighten me with this . once again i would like to say thanks to you sohil for helping me in such a short notice

Comment: You can override the default and add a loginprocessingurl in your spring securityconfiguration xml. Basic Auth doesnot provide any kind of security in a sense that the encoded bits and be decoded easily. Here's a great [video](https://javabrains.io/courses/javaee_advjaxrs/lessons/Sending-Basic-Auth-Requests) to understand about how Basic Auth works. There are couple of other Authentication such as Oath,Oath2 which you can look into for better security.  P.S. it really helps if you can vote up or a tick mark if i have answered your questions.

Comment: sohil can you pls provide some sample project or links for jwt and oauth .

Comment: The official [site](https://jwt.io/) is a good place to start for jwt. Here's a sample project for [OAuth2](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/)